# jQuery Animate or Load function not working in IE11

Tags: html, animation, load, jquery-animate, internet-explorer-11

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img#ucar").load(function () {
        $(this)
            .animate({ opacity: 1 / 2 }, 600)
            .animate({ top: "616px" }, 300)
            .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.ism {
    top: -400px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 345px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
}

#ucar {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="ism">
    <img id="ucar" src="images/img01.png" />
</div>
```

This code is working chrome but not working IE 11. I looked at other questions only answer I could not find on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens mainly to cached images that get loaded (*due to the caching*) before the script has time to execute.

Add a check to see if the image is already loaded and trigger the script..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img#ucar").load(function () {
        $(this)
            .animate({ opacity: 1 / 2 }, 600)
            .animate({ top: "616px" }, 300)
            .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
        return false;
    }).each(function(){
        if (this.complete){
            $(this).trigger('load');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/k7vz0dgv/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `.load()` function is not triggered in IE for some reason.

You could manually trigger the event by telling the image to load an empty string `""` so once its done, the callback function will execute:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // have a look at the load function
    $("img#ucar").load("",function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1 / 2            
        }, 600).animate({
            top: "616px"
        }, 300).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 0);
        return false;
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/dqp5m6mL/)**</kbd>